# Can winget install an older version of Python?

Tags: python, winget

Currently, the latest Python 3 offered through winget is 3.10.150.0:

```
Name                                                Id                                 Version      Match                   Source
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Python 3                                            Python.Python.3                    3.10.150.0   Command: python         winget
```

but I'd like to install 3.9 and keep using 3.9. Is it possible to do that with winget?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
winget install -e --id Python.Python -v 3.9.0
```

Comment: `winget show <package> --versions` displays all available versions. Also, Python has been split into different packages for Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: what does `-e` do? EDIT: -e,--exact  Find package using exact match

Answer (score 5):

First, you can see all the versions available with the following command:

```
PS C:\dev> winget search Python.Python

Name     Id                 Version   Source
---------------------------------------------
Python 3 Python.Python.3.9  3.9.7     winget
Python 3 Python.Python.3.8  3.8.10    winget
Python 3 Python.Python.3.7  3.7.9     winget
Python 3 Python.Python.3.6  3.6.8     winget
Python 3 Python.Python.3.5  3.5.4     winget
Python 3 Python.Python.3.4  3.4.4     winget
Python 3 Python.Python.3.3  3.3.5     winget
Python 3 Python.Python.3.2  3.2.5     winget
Python 3 Python.Python.3.10 3.10.6    winget
Python 3 Python.Python.3.1  3.1.4     winget
Python 3 Python.Python.3.0  3.0.1     winget
Python 2 Python.Python.2    2.7.18150 winget
```

In your case, the simplest way is to choose the Id you want, *Python.Python.3.9*, which would also allow the package manager to update it when patches come out.

```
PS C:\dev> winget install Python.Python.3.9

Found Python 3 [Python.Python.3.9] Version 3.9.7
This application is licensed to you by its owner.
Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages.
Downloading https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.7/python-3.9.7-amd64.exe
  ██████████████████████████████  27.5 MB / 27.5 MB
Successfully verified installer hash
Starting package install...
Successfully installed
```

This will do an automatic install with default options. However, the downside of this method is that each Python version will be installed under a Python directory tree, like `$LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\Python\Python39`, and it won't make any changes to your Path.

If you need Python to be available to all users and automatically added to the system Path, you're better off fine-tuning the installation using the interactive option *-i*, like so.

```
PS C:\dev> winget install -i Python.Python.3.9
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, winget can install an older version of Python. The most precise way to see the available versions is:

```
winget search --id Python.Python
```

This currently gives:

```
Name        Id                 Version   Source
------------------------------------------------
Python 2    Python.Python.2    2.7.18150 winget
Python 3    Python.Python.3.0  3.0.1     winget
Python 3    Python.Python.3.1  3.1.4     winget
Python 3    Python.Python.3.2  3.2.5     winget
Python 3    Python.Python.3.3  3.3.5     winget
Python 3    Python.Python.3.4  3.4.4     winget
Python 3    Python.Python.3.5  3.5.4     winget
Python 3    Python.Python.3.6  3.6.8     winget
Python 3    Python.Python.3.7  3.7.9     winget
Python 3    Python.Python.3.8  3.8.10    winget
Python 3    Python.Python.3.9  3.9.13    winget
Python 3.10 Python.Python.3.10 3.10.11   winget
Python 3.11 Python.Python.3.11 3.11.4    winget
Python 3.12 Python.Python.3.12 3.12.0b4  winget
```

So you can for example do `winget install -e --id Python.Python.3.9`.

This and more information about installing Python with winget can be found on https://winget.pro/winget-install-python/.

Answer (score 2):

in Windows 11 i used the command in this site:
https://winget.run/pkg/Python/Python.3

to get the version 3.7.7:

```
winget install -e --id Python.Python.3 -v 3.7.7150.0
```